Can I record (save file local) and get content realtime in android
I'm converting in-app speech to text and saving the audio file to a local file.
I found AudioRecord and SpeechRecognizer but when I run them, it cannot run at the same time, only AudioRecord works.
But if I run one of them it works.
I saw Google's Speech To Text and Amazon Transcribe but they're too expensive.
Any way to convert speech to text and save audio files locally using Android.
